# New York State Tax allowances (IT-2104 2012 vs 2011)

Tags: united-states, taxes, income, new-york

I have recently changed a job and trying to figure out how to fill-in the IT-2104 form for my new employer.

The biggest problem for me is that I cannot understand the amount of allowances to claim for the New York State and New York City (I'm resident of the NYC)
My situation is:

1. Married
2. Only one job
3. Spouse does not work
4. No kids
5. Allowances claimed on 2011 State/City tax is: 2

It's been pretty easy last time I did fill the It-2104. For 2011 there was a line saying:

> Married couples with only **one** spouse working and only **one** job

See the linked pdf: [IT-2104 for the year of 2011](http://dmna.ny.gov/hro/forms/IT-2104.pdf)
page 3, line 15

But!!! for the year of 2012 they have removed this line and it seems that I cannot claim
allowances as I did in 2011 which seems really strange to me.
the IT-2104 for 2012 is here:
[IT-2104 for the year of 2012](http://www.tax.ny.gov/pdf/current_forms/wt/it2104_fill_in.pdf)
See page 3 please

Moreover, my previous employer was using the same 2 allowances for the part of 2012
in the same way they did in 2011 and they didn't ask me to file a new form for 2012.

Now I'm getting really shocked: I'm afraid that my previous employer withheld too little State/City tax and I already owe some money and, moreover, I have to pay more City and State tax having the non-working spouse.

I will appreciate any help on this matter. Thank you.

Comment: Hm, I don't like my NYC + NYS taxes either but is the 2-3% NYC difference really threatening to put you underwater that much? I would focus more on the federal income tax.

Comment: @CQM, Thank you for your response. The thing is: I'm new to the US (moved a year ago) and I didn't know the amounts and if it is legal to put more allowances than IRS will "adjust" during the tax return verification. I'm not worrying about 2-3% in terms of money, I just need to be confident that my paperwork is done properly and I'd like to understand whether the State removed allowances for married couples with only one job.

Comment: Good luck with your research on that question, I would *HIGHLY* recommend Turbotax which is a software for determining both your federal, and state taxes. Similarly, HR Block offers cheap tax consulting services and have many locations around the city.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me of HR Block, I'd probably go and check with them. Regarding the Turobtax: I know, it a cool service, but I was not eligible for electronic submission (at all!) because of my residency status. So last year I've had fun of moving to NYC (can you imagine doing that without any credit score, etc) and doing my taxes :). Thanks again, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you owe money on your taxes last year?  If not, then you should keep the same number of allowances.  If your refund is annoyingly large, you can even claim more allowances.

You don't have to follow the formula on the worksheet to calculate the number of allowances.  If you use TurboTax, they will calculate how many allowances you should claim based on your particular circumstances.  The IRS formula makes conservative assumptions that may not apply to you.

Comment: I had a refund for both: Federal and State taxes, so I left the number of allowances the same for my State Tax. Thank you very much.